# Euclidean distance between np arrays

Tags: python, knn, euclidean-distance

I have two numpy arrays a and b:

a and b are the same dimensions, a could be a different size than b.

For instance:

```
a = [[1,2], ..., [5,7]]
b = [ [3,8], [4,7], ... [9,15] ]
```

Is there an easy way to compute the Euclidean distance between a and b such that this new array could be used in a k nearest neighbors learning algo.

Note: This is in python

Comment: So you want the Euclidean distance from each point in `a` to each point in `b`? Can you give a small example input *and* output?

Answer (score 2):

[scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) does this.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is k nearest neighbors, then there are more efficient ways than computing the full distance matrix (especially with many points). Check out scipy's [KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) if you want fast k-neighbors searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.spatial.distance.cdist like this:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

a = [[1,2], ..., [5,7]]
b = [ [3,8], [4,7], ... [9,15] ] 
dist = distance.cdist(a, b, 'euclidean')
```

This method can be used only if a and b have small number of elements.
If there are millions of elements than its slow and requires heavy space on memory.
I.e. lets say 'a' has 1 million elements and 'b' has 1000 elements. You will end up with O(m*n), where m=1000000 and b=1000.

Here you can see few methods are compared in terms of efficiency:
[Efficient and precise calculation of the euclidean distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794849/efficient-and-precise-calculation-of-the-euclidean-distance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy. Here an example:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([3, 0])
b = np.array([0, 4])

c = np.sqrt(np.sum(((a - b) ** 2)))
# c == 5.0
```