# How to efficiently calculate euclidean distance matrix for several timeseries

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have 6 timeseries data as follows namely t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and t6.

```
import numpy as np
series = np.array([
     [0., 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0., 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1., 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0., 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0., 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1., 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

I want to create a euclidean distance matrix from these 6 timeseries as in the format of (i.e. 6*6 where `x` denotes the corresponding euclidean distance):

```
     t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6
t1    0   x   x   x   x   x
t2    x   0   x   x   x   x
t3    x   x   0   x   x   x
t4    x   x   x   0   x   x
t5    x   x   x   x   0   x
t6    x   x   x   x   x   0
```

I am currently constructing this matrix manually as follows (In this SO question: [Efficient and precise calculation of the euclidean distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794849/efficient-and-precise-calculation-of-the-euclidean-distance) this method has got the hightest performance).

e.g., to calculate euclidean distance between t3 and t6.

```
def eudis(v1, v2):
    dist = [(a - b)**2 for a, b in zip(v1, v2)]
    dist = math.sqrt(sum(dist))
    return dist

eudis(t3, t6)
```

However, I am sure that there could be more easy and computationally efficient way to do this in python. Please let me know if you have suggestions.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Hi EmJ! Does this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401828/2402281) help you? More specifically, the usage of [np.linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)? I did not benchmark it but I'd assume that numpy is pretty much optimized (to be evaluated though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) to get the distance matrix:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
squareform(pdist(series))
```

---

Performance comparison with [pure numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258971/3944322) and [euclidean_distances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258673/3944322) solutions:
[image]

So for relatively small datasets (up to about 20 series with 200 elements each) `pdist` is fastest, for larger datasets `euclidean_disances` performs much better. `pure numpy` is mostly slower and may fail to allocate the intermediate array for large datasets.
Tested with `np.random.randint(0, 100, (n, 10*n)).astype('int16')`, numpy 1.17.4, scipy 1.4.1, sklearn 0.23.1, python 3.8.2, Win10 64bit.

Comment: thanks a lot for the nice comparison. since i have a larger dataset the insights you have provided is really useful. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop at all, for the euclidean distance between two arrays just compute the elementwise squares of the differences as:

```
def euclidean_distance(v1, v2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((v1 - v2)**2))
```

And for the distance matrix, you have [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

euclidean_distances(a).round(2)

array([[0.  , 2.83, 3.74, 0.  , 2.83, 3.74],
       [2.83, 0.  , 2.83, 2.83, 0.  , 2.83],
       [3.74, 2.83, 0.  , 3.74, 2.83, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 2.83, 3.74, 0.  , 2.83, 3.74],
       [2.83, 0.  , 2.83, 2.83, 0.  , 2.83],
       [3.74, 2.83, 0.  , 3.74, 2.83, 0.  ]])
```

---

```
np.allclose(
    eudis(series[2], series[3]),
    euclidean_distance(series[2], series[3])
)
# True
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer. from the comparison of @Stef this is the fastest for the larger datasets. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a distance matrix in simple numpy in one line, you don't need anything else.

```
np.sqrt(((series[:,None,:] - series)**2).sum(axis=2))
```

Comment: very nice solution, but you can run into memory problems for larger time series

Comment: You're right, it'll scale poorly for larger series.