# Pairwise comparison of rows in pandas dataframe and compute euclidean distance

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
region   country   val_a   val_b 
reg1     cntr1     0.5      0.7
reg2     cntr1     1        2
reg3     cntr1     2        1.2
reg1     cntr2     3        0.3
reg44    cntr2     0.2      0.7
```

I want to loop through this dataframe comparing each row with the other rows, finding the euclidean distance between `val_a` and `val_b` for each pair of rows and creating the following dataframe

```
source_region    source_country    dest_region    dest_country    distance
reg1              cntr1             reg2           cntr1            0.9
reg1               cntr1            reg3           cntr1            1.5
```

...

I can do a nested loop to create something like this but is there a more pythonic way to accomplish it? Please note that the `distance` column values are random in this example. You can use any formula you like to compute the euclidean distance, I just want to get the logic for pairwise comparison correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently calculate euclidean distance matrix for several timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258519/how-to-efficiently-calculate-euclidean-distance-matrix-for-several-timeseries)

Comment: Hello `user308827`. Was my answer useful or do you still need help doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinations from itertools. This can produce a list of all the combinations of row indices which can then be used to form a new dataframe. Clearly the distance calculation in the code below is merely illustrative. The code is done in steps so you can look at the intermediaries if required.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

idxs = list(combinations(df.index,2))
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((df.iloc[idx[0]].values, df.iloc[idx[1]].values)) for idx in idxs)
dfx.columns = ['s_region', 's_country', 's_1', 's_2', 'd_region', 'd_country', 'd_1', 'd_2']
dfx['distance'] = dfx['s_1']-dfx['s_2']+dfx['d_1']-dfx['d_2']
print(dfx)
```

which gives:

```
  s_region s_country  s_1  s_2 d_region d_country  d_1  d_2  distance
0     reg1     cntr1  0.5  0.7     reg2     cntr1  1.0  2.0      -1.2
1     reg1     cntr1  0.5  0.7     reg3     cntr1  2.0  1.2       0.6
2     reg1     cntr1  0.5  0.7     reg1     cntr2  3.0  0.3       2.5
3     reg1     cntr1  0.5  0.7    reg44     cntr2  0.2  0.7      -0.7
4     reg2     cntr1  1.0  2.0     reg3     cntr1  2.0  1.2      -0.2
5     reg2     cntr1  1.0  2.0     reg1     cntr2  3.0  0.3       1.7
6     reg2     cntr1  1.0  2.0    reg44     cntr2  0.2  0.7      -1.5
7     reg3     cntr1  2.0  1.2     reg1     cntr2  3.0  0.3       3.5
8     reg3     cntr1  2.0  1.2    reg44     cntr2  0.2  0.7       0.3
9     reg1     cntr2  3.0  0.3    reg44     cntr2  0.2  0.7       2.2
```

This assumes that source A, dest B is the same as source B, dest A since both distances will the same. If you want to have every source and every dest then use `permutations` instead of `combinations`.